# I want to Display all elements of a node by ID from an xml document and Folder of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, image, nodes

Thanks all for your help!

I'm new to programing and I'm trying to show all the elements of a node based on the ID.  My html doc is simple...loading the loadxmldoc.js file.  I need to load all the elements including images from a folder that correspond to the player ID.  What I really need a way to display character profiles based on a A-Z list.

I will probably make an xml file for each Player last name Initial...(e.g. Player_LastName_A.xml, Player_LastName_B.xml for each letter of the alphabet to load the xml faster)

If there is a simple  A-Z menu script that shows all of category "A" that would be great!

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="loadxmldoc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("Players.xml");

I want to show all player data (Name, Intro DOB etc.) based on ID=1234

</script>
</body>
```

```
My Players.xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Players>
  <Player ID="1234">
    <Name>Adam</Name>
    <Introduction>Blah Blah</Introduction>
    <DOB>01/01/2000</DOB>
    <Photo source="Players/3478.jpg">Players/3478.jpg</Photo>
    <Resides>Sheffield</Resides>
    <ProYear>2011</ProYear>
    <BestRanking>2012</BestRanking>
  </Player>
  <player ID="1235">
    <Name>Adam B</Name>
        <Name>Adam</Name>
    <Introduction>Blah Blah</Introduction>
    <DOB>01/01/2000</DOB>
    <Photo source="Players/3478.jpg">Players/3478.jpg</Photo>
    <Resides>Sheffield</Resides>
    <ProYear>2011</ProYear>
    <BestRanking>2012</BestRanking>
  </player>
</Players>
```

---

```
My loadxmldoc.js file:

// JavaScript Document
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // code for IE5 and IE6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```